# How to create a large empty file quickly on Time Capsule internal drive?

Tags: terminal, network, time-capsule

My old Time Capsule died so I decided to buy a new one which has a 2TB disk instead of the old 1TB disk and I got it up and running.

For now I would like to limit the Time Machine backup to around 1TB and instead of repartitioning the drive just create 100GB files with "mkfile -n 100gb emptyfile" on the /Volumes/TC/Data path.  This takes ages as apparently the "-n" does not avoid writing the full set of zeros to the file.

Is there a way to create a very big file on the TC from my Mac so the diskspace is allocated but without actually writing all the zeros?

Comment: Are you connecting to the time capsule over SMB or AFP? I don’t think it matters for sparse file creation and you may need actual data that’s not trivially zero to occupy space on that network file server.

Comment: Why don't you simply enter `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine MaxSize 1000000` (size is in MiB) in Terminal to limit the TM backup size? This should work on external drives as well as TM backup servers like TC!

Comment: @klanomath I don't like messing with the settings, and the default behavior of "start cleaning when the drive is full" is fine with me.  For now I just fill it up with a bunch of 100 GB files.  When I found that modern Wifi is up to 30 megabytes/second it is just an hour each.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. This is like filling the archive rooms of your royal library reserved for future use with some arbitrary filling material instead of hanging up an indication sign *(Archive 2019-20XX)*.

Comment: @klanomath Different taste I guess.   I don't want a global arbitrary undocumented limit  snuck in  under the hood in my backup scheme.  So for now reducing the disk space available is a cheap and tested solution for me.  The question was not about changing TM but creating these files faster.

Comment: There is a good security reason for overwriting with something. If it didn't you would be able to read the content of previously deleted files - potentially belonging to someone else.  That may not apply with a new disk, but the security principle of overwriting is sound.  So I hope you don't find a way - sorry.